# Python write dictionary into excel

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I want to write a dictionary into an excel file. I always get some error messages, can someone explain me how to do?

```
    import sys
    import argparse

    import pyexcel
    import pyexcel.ext.xls
    import os

#reading input..

    dict = {'Kalibrierwerte':
                 [array_1]
        ,
             'Messwerte':
                 [array_2]
        }

    book=pyexcel.get_book(adict=dict)

    book.save_as("../data/output2.xls")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

when I run this code,I get this error:

```
'File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\sources_init_.py", line 102, in _get_book raise NotImplementedError(MESSAGE_ERROR_NO_HANDLER) NotImplementedError: No suitable plugins imported or installed'
```

I tried different ways to write the output, but none was succesful.

Comment: For posted code: 'File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\sources\__init__.py", line 102, in _get_book
    raise NotImplementedError(MESSAGE_ERROR_NO_HANDLER)
NotImplementedError: No suitable plugins imported or installed'

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `pyexcel`, but I think you could save your data with csv format which supported by excel also.

It's a example below:

```
import pandas as pd

array_1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'i', 'j']
array_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
your_dict = {       # do not use `dict` to name a variable
    'Kalibrierwerte': array_1,
    'Messwerte': array_2,
}

# convert `dict` to `pandas.DataFrame` and save to csv file
d = pd.DataFrame(your_dict)
d.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Comment: I need different sheets, so, i dont want to have a csv. (There are more than this 2 small arrays, every array is one sheet)

Comment: @Miguel13366 what is the keyword parameter `adict` in your code `book=pyexcel.get_book(adict=dict)`? I can't find it in the [documentation of get_book](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/pyexcel.get_book.html?highlight=get_book#pyexcel.get_book)

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the dictionary and getbook.

See code below

```
dict_out = {'Kalibrierwerte': array_1,
            'Messwerte':array_2
            }

book=pyexcel.get_book(bookdict=dict_out)
book.save_as("../out/output.xls")
```

Comment: you could have used one liner: pyexcel.save_book_as(bookdict=dict_out, dest_file_name="../out/output.xls")